# Java Spring Framework. Declare classes as bean only

Tags: java, spring

I am learning Java Spring in parallel with tackling a problem.
My question is:
Can I have a pool of classes defined as beans only (without them declared in the JAVA source)?
When the application runs it will do computations only on the declared classes available in the beans.

So for instance I have beans for the classes **A**, **B** ,**C**; But I have no declaration in the java code for this classes. I may group them together under an Interface say **DocumentationVersionSpecificTag**
Is this approach feasible ?

Comment: honestly, your question seems unclear. Would you give a better example and more detailed one.

Comment: As soon as you declare a dependency to a bean of type `DocumentationVersionSpecificTag` and none is available, the application startup will fail

Comment: what do  you mean "I have no declaration in the java code for this classes"?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to inject objects that are not in your source code using `@Autowired`, you can achieve this using a configuration class, a class annotated with @Configuration, and configure these classes as beans in it, using @Bean:

```
@Configuration
public class ProjectConfiguration{

  @Bean
  public A configureA(){
    return new A(); // use the suitable constructor you want
  }

  @Bean
  public B configureB(){
    return new B(); // use the suitable constructor you want
  }

  @Bean
  public C configureC(){
    return new C(); // use the suitable constructor you want
  }

}
```

After you can inject these classes with `@Autowired`:

```
@Autowired
A a;
```

For more details, see this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html).

Comment: Yes, I want to know if I can inject classes without them being declared in my source. 
I need this because I have a documentation for a data representation format that is non-xml.
But the documentation comes in different versions with some definitions new others missing or different relations.

In your example and link (will read in a minute) The class **A**  is not declared anyware in the code right ?

Comment: class A is declared when you want to use it. As I see, in your source code you don't like to call A at any cost, but you can use DocumentationVersionSpecificTag interface instead?

Comment: I have read the link. I will do some experiments with @Autowire when I get home. 
Thank you :)

Comment: @SMarius, welcome, could you please answer my question above, in the previous comment?